# What is the significance of 'energy ellipsoid'?

Tags: polarization, tensor-calculus

Well, today I was reading [Tensors](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_31.html#Ch31-S3) by Feynman in his lectures, where he introduced the concept of '*energy ellipsoid*'.

This is the following excerpt:

> [...] the polarization tensor can be measured by just measuring the energy required to polarize the crystal in various directions. Suppose we apply an $E$-field with only an $x$- and a $y$-component; then according to Eq. (31.7),
>   $$u_P=\frac{1}{2} [α_{xx}E^2_x+(α_{xy}+α_{yx})E_xE_y+α_{yy}E^2_y].\tag{31.8}$$
>   With an $E_x$ alone, we can determine $α_{xx};$ with an $E_y$ alone, we can determine $α_{yy};$ with both $E_x$ and $E_y,$ we get an extra energy due to the term with $(α_{xy}+α_{yx}).$ Since the $α_{xy}$ and $α_{yx}$ are equal, this term is $2α_{xy}$ and can be related to the energy.
>
> The energy expression, Eq. (31.8), has a nice geometric interpretation. Suppose we ask what fields $E_x$ and $E_y$ correspond to some given energy density—say $u_0.$ That is just the mathematical problem of solving the equation
>   $$α_{xx}E^2_x+2α_{xy}E_xE_y+α_{yy}E^2_y=2u_0.$$This is a quadratic equation, so if we plot $E_x$ and $E_y$ the solutions of this equation are all the points on an ellipse. The vector $\boldsymbol E$ with components $E_x$ and $E_y$ can be drawn from the origin to the ellipse. So **such an “energy ellipse” is a nice way of “visualizing” the polarization tensor.**

[image]

> If we now generalize to include all three components, the electric vector $E$ in any direction required to give a unit energy density gives a point which will be on the surface of an ellipsoid. The shape of this ellipsoid of constant energy uniquely characterizes the tensor polarizability.

[image]

> Now an ellipsoid has the nice property that it can always be described simply by giving the directions of three “principal axes” and the diameters of the ellipse along these axes. The “principal axes” are the directions of the longest and shortest diameters and the direction at right angles to both. They are indicated by the axes $a$, $b$, and $c$. With respect to these axes, the ellipsoid has the particularly simple equation
>   $$α_{aa}E^2_a+α_{bb}E^2_b+α_{cc}E^2_c=2u_0.$$
>   So with respect to these axes, the dielectric tensor has only three components that are not zero: $α_{aa}$, $α_{bb}$, and $α_{cc}$.

Many things did Feynman write; but really I didn't get what this ellipsoid really tells about the energy of polarizability.

The ellipse is just the locus of the electric field vector for a constant energy. That's it?

What is actually '*energy ellipsoid*'? How does this ellipsoid tell about the tensor components of polarizability?

Can anyone please explain me what the significance of this energy ellipsoid is? How does it tell about the tensor of polarizability?

Comment: Yes, it is pretty much a visualization thing. Now, if you go deeper in to non-linear optics it becomes a very useful (at least to me) way of matching things up. How such a visualization helps you (or anybody else) is, of course, a personal thing. But, the symmetry of the 'ellipsoid' will match the symmetry of the relevant tensor, be it elasticity, dc polarization, optical coefficients, whatnot...

Comment: @Jon Custer: Feynman says it is related to the tensor components of polarizability but the ellipsoid is just the locus of the electric field vectors; how could this ellipsoid tell about the tensors of polarizability? I'm not getting that.

Comment: Well, in a simple 1-D case, how is the polarizability related to the electric field? Now extend to 3D.

Comment: @JonCuster: Okay; but if I just give you the figure, could you get those tensor components; they are just the locus of the electric field which satisfy that ellipsoid equation, isn't it?

Comment: Correct. A certain electric field induces a particular polarization, and a given polarization implies a specific electric field. The 'ellipsoid' is an easy way to think about it, although of course it can be much more complicated if there are cross terms (shear in elasticity) in the tensor (i.e. the polarization along x depends on an electric field along y). And, choosing the wrong set of axes as the basis also leads to that problem...

Comment: And, as noted, some folks 'see' this and think it is intuitive, while others think it is really confusing. Everybody's intuition is a little different, which is one of the reasons I hate when people ask questions about intuition since I don't live in their heads...